# Python - Remove Square symbol from text string

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, unicode

```
a='ÿþ"[]B[]a[]l[]a[]n[]c[]e'
```

NOTE: The open and close square brackets represent this square symbol.  I cannot however copy and paste the square symbol into here to show you exactly what I'm looking at.

The characters in 'a' represent the beginning of a file I've downloaded.  It is a csv file, unicode.  How do I remove these unwanted characters?  I would just like to recover the word 'balance' from a.

The code I've used to simply this example:

```
fi = open(path+fn, 'r')
data = fi.read()
fi.close()
print(data)
```

Where `fn` is a csv file.

Tried:

```
data=data.encode()
d=replace('\x00','')
```

which produced error:

```
TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object
```

Comment: I don't know Python but ÿþ is a utf-16 BOM so look for a way to specify encoding when you open the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the right encoding when opening the file. Try

```
open(path+fn, 'r', encoding="utf-16")
```

(I'm guessing utf-16 because ASCII characters seem to be encoded in two bytes in the sample string)

Comment: Spot on.  Exactly what I wanted.  Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with encoding, `string.printable` is a list of 'printable' chars which may be what you're looking for.

```
>>> from string import printable
>>> best_string_ever = filter(lambda x: x in printable, a)
>>> best_string_ever
'"Balance'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can show the character value, then you can use the strip(u'\uxxx') command

use the replace() method

```
newstring = textstring.replace(u'\uxxx', '')
```

In this case pass in the actual character encoding that you want.